# Resolving IE compatability issues seemingly caused by Microsoft's own software

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

We're using a third party content management system built on ASP.NET. The pages seem to display in IE9 mode on IE11. I used the MS IE10 compat inspector tool http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/20/ie10-compat-inspector.aspx to try and work out why the page is not displaying in IE10 or Edge mode. (The HTML5 feature that I'm trying to use should display in IE10 or 11.) The only warnings the tool gives are about Javascript which is using `window.navigator` to do browser sniffing.

The code that is using `window.navigator` is in a file called webresource.axd:

```
var __nonMSDOMBrowser = (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf('explorer') == -1);
```

which itself seems to be part of ASP.NET.

There are no javascript warnings or errors. Here's one of the pages:
https://secure.wycliffe.org.uk/NetCommunity/SSLPage.aspx?pid=283. This is with IIS6 on Windows Server 2003.

Could this be the cause of the IE9 mode problem? (I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the document.)

Is MS's own tool really complaining about bad practise in it's own software?

Comment: What isn't displaying? The page? An element? Are you getting a javascript warning or error? Could your issue be caused by CSS? Is it possible for us to see the issue as it is difficult to troubleshoot from this description.

Comment: The .net framework has done all sorts of silly things over the years, so yes, it's likely to trigger errors in the compat inspector. You need to make sure your server has all the latest .net hotfixes installed, which include IE10 and IE11 (etc) compatibility patches for .net's browser detection code. .net 4.5 drops the browser detection stuff in favour of feature detection, thankfully. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx for more.

Comment: @ChrisHardie I mean "why the page is not displaying IE10 or edge mode". I'll edit the question. There are no javascript warnings or errors. I guess it could be caused by CSS. What sort of CSS problems would cause it?

Comment: Do you have `X-UA-Compatible` in you page head set to IE9?

Comment: @OllyHodgson It is up to date with all patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha! It's because your server is sending the pages down with an `X-UA-Compatible` header, telling Internet Explorer to use IE9 mode.

To see it, open https://secure.wycliffe.org.uk/NetCommunity/SSLPage.aspx?pid=283 in IE10, and press F12 to bring up the developer tools. Switch to the Network tab, press Start and refresh the page. Once it's loaded, double-click on the first item, then switch to the Response Headers tab.

You should see a header in there: `X-UA-Compatible`: `IE=9`.

To force IE to use the latest rendering mode, go into the IIS configuration, find where it's being applied, and either remove it, or change it to a newer version, e.g. `IE=10`. Alternatively, `IE=edge` will always use the latest version's standards mode rendering engine. Be aware it's probably there for a reason, though! We've had to use that header in the past as a short-term workaround for IE10 issues in legacy .net applications.

See [MSDN: Defining document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I hadn't thought of looking in the headers. It wasn't set in the IIS configuration, so was probably in the third party software. However I was able to specify it  in IIS and even though both headers came out, IE seemed to pay attention to the IE=10 one.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you tested with IE11 yet? :)

Comment: Actually it was IE11. I'll fix the question. It should display even in IE10 though.